# Production Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am struggling to get Heroku to use Sidekiq as the job handler in production.

Locally - it appears like Sidekiq is taking the email jobs, as the logs below show from Sidekiq's stdout:

```
2018-09-15T05:10:05.164Z 5256 TID-ovryxfcwc ActionMailer::DeliveryJob     JID-156e566ba5bc0136ef18ee45 INFO: start
2018-09-15T05:10:06.838Z 5256 TID-ovryxfcwc ActionMailer::DeliveryJob    JID-156e566ba5bc0136ef18ee45 INFO: done: 1.674 sec
2018-09-15T05:10:06.839Z 5256 TID-ovryxfcwc ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-c97af1298abad5b8caebfcd4 INFO: start
2018-09-15T05:10:06.935Z 5256 TID-ovryxfcwc ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-c97af1298abad5b8caebfcd4 INFO: done: 0.096 sec
2018-09-15T05:10:06.937Z 5256 TID-ovryxfcwc ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-0cca4280f85cd9f41325a2af INFO: start
2018-09-15T05:10:07.035Z 5256 TID-ovryxfcwc ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-0cca4280f85cd9f41325a2af INFO: done: 0.098 sec
```

However, in production in Heroku, the logs show that all mail taks are performed by the Web Dyno. I would assume that the Worker Dyno should be processing the ActionMailer job, but never appears to get to sidekiq.

Under config/initializers/active_job.rb I have:

```
Rails.application.config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

Where am I going wrong getting my application to work in production with sidekiq the way it does in test?

Answer (score 0):

It was me being stupid and out of practice - of course the worker is running sidekiq - and it has to call the web worker to actually do the job.

Confirmed by looking at the stats by enabling the sidekiq route to check the jobs were run.